# Azure Devops - Change ticket assignee using PR markdown

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure Devops, I can add markdown in a pull request's description to automatically change a linked ticket's state once the pr is completed, like this:

```
NewState: #TicketNumber
```

for example:

```
Committed: #1000
```

Is there a way to also change the assignee? I have tried:

```
@PersonName: #TicketNumber
```

but it didn't apply the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the work item rules to do this.

For example, you can create the rule as when the work item state is changed to completed (**`Closed`**, **`Done`**, **`Completed`**, etc.), set the assignee to the specified user.

[image]

To view more details, you can see "[**Add a rule to a work item type**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops)".

However, this method will always assign the work item to the same user who is specified in the rule whenever the work item state is changed to completed.

If you want to dynamically set the assignee according to the user you mentioned in the description, this methods is not available. In this situation, you can try to set up a pipeline with the following steps:

- Try to get the linked work item ID, and the account information (username and email address) of the user you want to assign the work item to.
- Try using the API "[**Work Items - Update**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)" to changed the assignee.